# "Failed to download repository information" on 16.04

Tags: updates, update-manager

I know people have asked this question but the solutions seem to differ and I haven't found mine yet. I get the response as stated in the subject title. Here's the output in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [1,189 B]           
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]         
Get:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Hit:8 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                           
Err:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg                 
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
Get:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipelight/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Fetched 308 kB in 1s (200 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6494C6D6997C215E
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate and your answer worked. Should I delete or accept dufte's answer?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the link posted by Manoj Sawai your problem is related with google chrome and the changed GPG key.

The following command should import Google's updated GPG Key and therefor fix your issue:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

After that re-run your `sudo apt update` commands and you should be fine again.